# Getting average of cells

Tags: excel

I need a formula that will look at 7 cells and take the average of the non-zero values.

ex:  if cell 4 is 0 then average for other 6 cells

cells:
35
45
51
0
65
42
39

average would be 46.16  only used 6 columns with value in them

Comment: It would be nice to know what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

use AVERAGEIFS():

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:G1,A1:G1,">0")
```

[image]